# About labels in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a program that currently launches a winform in full screen, hiding the task bar.
If I manage to keep fiddling with the cordinates to get a text label to sit in the bottom right corner of the screen. will it always appear there regardless of what size screen or computer is running the program?

Comment: Use the `Anchor` property; see the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the label properties, set the Anchor from Top Left to Bottom Right.

Comment: not to heckle you further but what can anchors...anchor to?

Comment: Anchor is always relevant to the container of the anchored control. So, if you have that property set within, say, a panel, then it locks itself to the bottom right coordinates of that panel.